# Creating/using my own 'custom' character

Tags: bash, character-encoding

Is it possible to create your own ascii character that you can use?
If so, how would it be done?

Now my use case would be something like this: Let's say I created the character `#12345`, and I am generating some custom logs for some script I made, and I want each field to be separated by my new character, such as:

```
ID #12345 Host #12345 User #12345 Message #12345 Timestamp
1 #12345 host1 #12345 user1 #12345 This user did this this and that #12345 11:11:11
2 #12345 host1 #12345 user2 #12345 This other user did this new thing #12345 11:11:51
```

So the reason I want a custom character, is because I want the text in each field to be able to have ANY character in them (and it would be incredibly unlikely for them to have my custom character), and then I could easily manipulate it with awk with `awk -F '#12345' '{print $4}'` to get the message, regardless of what the message actually has in it, which I usually had problems with in json formatted output because there's a `,` between key value pairs, while there may also be a `,` in the message.

It's not a duplicate because my question is not "how to parse json", that's just my use case. My question is about making a custom character that I can use.

Comment: Assuming you mean unicode rather than ascii... A solution would relate to the Unicode Character Database (https://www.unicode.org/ucd/). Looking at the "Basic Questions" in their FAQ, it seems you might be aiming to use an unassigned character, which apparently should be within the "private use areas" to be a "conformant Unicode implementation" (https://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#12). For more info (i.e. to be inundated by FAQs) see https://www.unicode.org/faq/

Comment: Incidentally, outside the "private use areas" it might be difficult to just pick an unassigned character at random... U+12345 is defined as "CUNEIFORM SIGN URU TIMES KI"

Comment: So there is no way to just use one that's most likely to not be assigned by anything?

Comment: That was just an example, In reality it could be any way, I would create a script to fit my needs, but what I do need is to replace a field delimiter with something that nothing else will ever use, which I thought would be a custom character. Even if there are better ways of doing it, I still would like to know how to do this particular thing.

Comment: @DavidYockey That's not a comment!  That's an answer!  Please post an answer, ping me [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote! **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

The only possible answer to your exact question is "No.  ASCII characters are a pre-defined set of 7-bit characters with values from 0-127, and with specific meanings assigned to each of those values.  There is no scope for adding to or changing them".

I'm guessing that's not the question you're really asking, though.  You want to know if there is (or can be) guaranteed unique delimiter which can be used with any input data.

As a general rule, the answer is no - it's not possible, it doesn't exist.

In specific cases (i.e. input data with known or easily discoverable characteristics), however, it's usually possible to find one character that is either unlikely or guaranteed to be impossible to find in a data field.

Most people use TAB as an "unlikely to be in the data" delimiter.   `:` is popular too (e.g. /etc/passwd) unless there are time fields or other data that typically use colons.  And commas are usable in many cases.

Some people use properly formed CSV (i.e. **with** quotes around string fields which may contain the delimiter).  And others use JSON or XML or other structured text formats.  These require a good parser to accurately extract data from them.

In theory, you could write such a parser in bash.  In practice, you really don't want to - it's far more work than just using the right tool for the job....or the right language (it's far easier to write a good parser in C or perl or python than in a slow & very limited language like bash)

---

extra info:  in your other question, you seemed to think that there's something wrong with using "3rd party tools" in a bash script.  Nothing could be further from the truth - that is a shell script's role, to act as the "glue" and "co-ordinator" between multiple third-party tools.  It is what sh/bash is good at.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I did try to create a json parser in bash, but gave up on the idea. Now I was thinking of learning a programming language that would be able to easily do this, and that is present in most linux distros, some people suggested python, while somebody else suggested JavaScript because apparently it's very easy to parse json in it. What would you recommend?

Comment: For the kind of tasks you've shown in your questions, I'd just use existing tools like `jq` or `json` (or `xmlstarlet` or `xml2` for xml data) - i.e. use the right tool for the job.    Otherwise, I'd be inclined to use awk or perl.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean UNICODE rather than ASCII, a solution would relate to the [Unicode Character Database](https://unicode.org/ucd).

Looking at the "Basic Questions" in their FAQ, it seems you might be aiming to use an unassigned character, which apparently should be within the "private use areas" to be a ["conformant Unicode implementation"](https://unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#12).

For more info (i.e. to be inundated by FAQs) [have a look here](https://unicode.org/faq).

Comment: Someone just pinged me *[in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532172/creating-using-my-own-custom-character?noredirect=1#comment989476_532172)* that you answered.  When you ping someone in the answer itself, it doesn't work, so I've removed that and upvoted!  **:-)**

Comment: Pings only work in the comments... Good to know! Thanks, @Fabby! :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be overly difficult to parse the log file as shown *without* the proposed `#12345` magic delimiter. I'll be the first to point out that this suggestion doesn't satisfy "*I want the text in each field to be able to have ANY character in them*" but I'm going to suggest this anyway on the basis that hostnames, usernames, and timestamps *probably* don't have spaces.

```
cat log

ID Host User Message Timestamp
1 host1 user1 This user did this this and that 11:11:11
2 host1 user2 This other user did this new thing 11:11:51

while IFS=' ' read -r id host user message
do
    timestamp="${message##* }" message="${message% *}"
    printf "%s - %s - %s - %s - %s\n" "$id" "$host" "$user" "$message" "$timestamp"
done <log

ID - Host - User - Message - Timestamp
1 - host1 - user1 - This user did this this and that - 11:11:11
2 - host1 - user2 - This other user did this new thing - 11:11:51
```

Comment: And another upvote! **0:-)** Thanks for pointing me to the other one...